# Add text once to input on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code applied to a input test type `onClick="this.value+='http://'"`, but I want to modify it so that it only adds http:// the first time the user clicks the input.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you're using this error-prone code. To meet your wishes, here you go: `onClick="this.value+='http://';this.onclick='';"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is obvious (slightly modified, to prefix text with `http://`):

```
onClick="this.value = 'http://' + this.value; this.onclick = '';"
```

However, this method is error-prone, and ugly. You probably want to force a text to be prefixed with `http://`. The code will not work if the user navigates to the input field using keys (such as <kbd>tab</kbd>).

An improved approach would be:

```
onfocus="if (this.value.substring(0,6)!=='http://') this.value = 'http://' + this.value;"
```

Still, depending on your exact application, other methods are even more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

you can set a counter variable in global and check if it is equal to 1 add `http://` and else 
do not add.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <input type="text" onClick=" this.value.indexOf( 'http://' ) != 0 ? this.value = 'http://' + this.value : this.value; " />
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The closest right solution is: `onClick="if (this.value.indexOf( 'http://' ) != 0) this.value = 'http://' + this.value;"`.